# python pandas: selecting one column from a multiple values

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I want to use only column index 0 to put all my dict[values], datas.
but whenever I use multiple values like "C","D", index increases 
I want my values to be added vertically without increasing index on excel.
*
 I know I should change `orient='index'` part for my desired expected output.
 Tried looking for this particular code but I couldn't... any help?

```
android_report_data_set ={
    "A":["APPLE"],
    "B":["KIWI"],
    "C":["MANGOJUICE","WATERMELONJUICE","DURIANJUICE"]}
    "D":["RED","PINK","BLACK"]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(android_report_data_set, orient='index')

df.transpose()



*EXPECTED OUTPUT

+----+-----------------+
|    |  0              |
+----+-----------------+
| A  | APPLE           |  
| B  | KIWI            |  
| C  | MANGOJUICE      |
|    | WATERMELONJUICE |
|    | DURIANJUICE     |
| D  | RED             |
|    | PINK            |
|    | BLACK           | 
+----+-----------------+

*OUTPUT
+----+------------+---------------------+--------------+
|    | 0          | 1                   | 2            |
+----+------------+---------------------+--------------+
| A  | APPLE      |                     |              |
| B  | KIWI       |                     |              |
| C  | MANGOJUICE | WATERMELONJUICE     | DURIANJUICE  |
| D  | RED        | PINK                | BLACK        |
+----+------------+---------------------+--------------+
```

Thank you!!

Comment: you would need a  multiindex for such a view , try stack: `df.stack().to_frame()` , you can also export the same to csv if required with `index=False`

Comment: shall my index=False should be located inside  `writer=pd.ExcelWriter('report1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')`inside this statement?

Comment: `df.stack().to_frame().to_excel(.....,index=False)`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) by first level for remove second level and then convert tpo one column `DataFrame` by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df1 = df.stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).to_frame()
print (df1)
                 0
A            APPLE
B             KIWI
C       MANGOJUICE
C  WATERMELONJUICE
C      DURIANJUICE
D              RED
D             PINK
D            BLACK
```

If need only first values in index you can replace duplicated values to empty strings:

```
df1.index = df1.index.where(~df1.index.duplicated(), '')
print (df1)
                 0
A            APPLE
B             KIWI
C       MANGOJUICE
   WATERMELONJUICE
       DURIANJUICE
D              RED
              PINK
             BLACK
```

Last write fo file, `index=False` should be omit for avoid remove index values `('A','B','C','D')`:

```
df1.to_excel(file)
```

Comment: thank you!!  what if I want the dict(key) to remain safe  A,B,C,D.... instead of indexing rows?